# How do I recreate db and import JIRA data from previous automated export

Tags: java, database, jira

I have my own local instance of Atlassian JIRA Issue Server on a hosted server. Unfortunately the hard-drive failed on the hosted server the administrator replaced the drive and recovered the program and data directories, but unfortunately the  adminstrator had not actually made a  back up of the database :(

Luckily it seems that JIRA automatically does a data export of the data, i have daily zip files such as `2015-Apr-20--0555.zip` in

```
atlassian/application-data/jira/export
```

But what is the easiest way to import this data ?

The server is starting up but I can't access any admin pages, how do I go about recreating the database (i dont remember any details of how I did this the first time). Should I reinstall jira from scratch or can I fix the existing installation to accept the export file.

Comment: Personally I'd be contacting Atlassian for assistance with the data recovery. At least then you can guarantee that you're adhering to best practices.

Comment: It seems the "easiest" is to reinstall Jira, and then import that export.

Answer (score -2):

if the data exported as SQL then you can easy use MYSQLAdmin to import the data to the New JIRA Database, but if the data is comma separated file then you can use MYSQL command for that, based on what you say you cant do that because you cant reach to the server command windows, then you can create simple PHP file to insert the data from the zip file to the DB this link may help you

http://coyotelab.org/php/upload-csv-and-insert-into-database-using-phpmysql.html

Comment: This assumes he is using MySQL as the database - It could just as easily be PostgreSQL or Oracle. Likewise his Admin pages are down - this does not mean he is unable to SSH into the remote machine.

Comment: The data created by the JIRA automated backups is neither SQL nor CSV format (it's XML).